# Objective-C ARC and GCC ({}) extension compatibility?

Tags: objective-c, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor, automatic-ref-counting

I'm converting some Objective-C code to ARC that makes heavy use of the GCC ["Statements and Declarations in Expressions"  extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs) `({})`.

The GCC extension is being used in preprocessor macros to create Objective-C objects.  The actual macros are fairly complex, so here is a contrived example to simplify things.  Assume for the purposes of my example that the `_x` parameter is always `NSString *`:

```
#define f(_x) ({ NSString *x = (_x); [NSString stringWithString: x]; })
```

This macro would of course be called like so:

```
void foo() { NSString *s = f(@"foo"); }
```

In the pre-ARC environment this works just fine.  The object created by the `stringWithString:` call is an autoreleased object and the GCC extension assigns it to `s`.

After converting to ARC (Xcode 4.4.1) however the object is released immediately when the statement block exits (I confirmed this by instantiating an object that `NSLog()`s it's `dealloc`).

I've tried modifying the macro with typecasts like:

```
#define f(_x) ({ NSString *x = (_x); (__autoreleasing id) [NSString stringWithString: x]; })
```

and

```
#define f(_x) ({ NSString *x = (_x); (NSString __autoreleasing *) [NSString stringWithString: x]; })
```

but both forms result in a compilation error:

*`Explicit ownership qualifier on cast has no effect`*

It appears then that ARC and this GCC extension are incompatible.

Is this so or am I missing something simple that tells ARC not to immediately release the object?

I do have some options, the most attractive of which at the moment seems to be to convert all of these macros to `__inline__` functions but I have quite a bit of code to deal with.  I'm really hoping for a quick fix so any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Frankly, I would bite the bullet and go with changing them to functions which is why they always should have been.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been debugging this for a few hours now and found a solution so I'll answer my own question.  FWIW I agree with CRD and think it's a bug--I'll file a report with Apple.

It happens that the "contrived example" I made up for my question actually works (doh).  As I mentioned originally the macros I'm working with are much more complicated and they don't.  I've discovered though that they *will* if I return the created object through a temporary as the last statement in the statement block.  When written like that ARC doesn't release the object.  I assume there's some very narrow RVO-type code in clang and it's colliding with the ARC parser.

At any rate, the workaround looks this (scroll to the very end of the line):

```
#define f(_x) ({ NSString *x = (_x); NSString *y = [NSString stringWithString: x]; y; })
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting observation, might be worth a compiler bug report as the result is clearly contra to the defined semantics.

You could move the assignment into your macro:

```
#define f(lhs, _x) ({ NSString *x = (_x); lhs = [NSString stringWithString: x]; })
```

which should solve the release issue. But switching to inline functions is probably better!

Comment: Nice answer.  I considered putting the assignment in the macro but would have had to change hundreds of files that use it.  That makes me nervous which is why I was looking for a quick & dirty fix.

Answer (score 0):

The catch is that your NSString *x inside the {} is not defined outside the {}. So it can not be referenced afterwards and ARC releasing it is correct. Your macro is not supposed to work in the first place as the return value of a { } block is undefined in my eyes.

this should do the trick

```
#define f(_x) (NSString *x = (_x); [NSString stringWithString: x]
```

but might have side effects due to naming and being multiple statements.

Going for a inline function is a more logical way of doing it.

Comment: The return value of a ({}) block is not undefined in GCC--it's a *documented extension*.  The purpose of an embedded statement block is specifically to define locals so macro arguments don't evaluate twice.  I would -1 your answer as not helpful (but won't since you're new) because you've missed the point entirely...  I understand the mechanics, I know I can fix it with an inline function, etc.  This is a documented GCC extension that appears to be incompatible with ARC; I am looking for clarification/validation/workarounds/etc. on that issue.

Answer (score 0):

PS: if ({}) is a GCC specific macro extensions I'm not fully aware of, then be warned that Apple now uses clang, not GCC as default.